# Can a bounded sequence plus an unbounded sequence produce a bounded sequence?

Tags: analysis

Can a bounded sequence plus an unbounded sequence produce a bounded sequence?
This seems very counterintuitive to me, and I would like to apply this knowledge to the Algebraic Limit Theorem.

Comment: *Hint:* $b_n = (a_n + b_n) - a_n$. Can it be that $(a_n)$ is bounded, $(b_n)$ is unbounded, and their sum $(a_n + b_n)$ is bounded?

Comment: The sequence obtained by summing a bounded sequence and a sequence which takes arbitrarily large values will also take arbitrarily large values. Two unbounded sequences, however, when chosen properly may cancel each other and produce a bounded sequence.

Answer (score 1):

There exists an $M\geq 0$ such that $|a_n|\leq M$. Suppose there exists an $N\geq0$ such that $|a_n+b_n|\leq N$ (for all$n\in\Bbb N$).
Then
$$
|b_n| = |b_n+a_n-a_n| \leq |b_n+a_n| + |a_n| \leq N+M
$$
so $(b_n)_{n\in\Bbb N}$ is bounded.

Comment: So, the answer to the question is no.